# Site 1 cannot connect to Site 2? error: no route to site2: dropping message

Tags: jboss, redhat, infinispan, infinispan-9

I currently have an infinispan v.9.4.8 image with modified clustered.xml code for two sites. I am building the image through docker for 2 servers. On server 1 (ie hostname1) I have site1, and on server 2 I have site2.

ie relevant clustered.xml code in server1:

```
...
                   <relay site="site1">
                        <remote-site name="site2" channel="xsite"/>
                        <property name="relay_multicasts">false</property>
                    </relay>
                   <backups>
...
                        <backup site="site2" failure-policy="FAIL" strategy="SYNC" enabled="true">
                            <take-offline min-wait="60000" after-failures="3" />
                        </backup>
                    </backups>
```

and relevant clustered.xml code in server2:

```
...
                   <relay site="site2">
                        <remote-site name="site1" channel="xsite"/>
                        <property name="relay_multicasts">false</property>
                    </relay>
                   <backups>
...
                        <backup site="site1" failure-policy="FAIL" strategy="SYNC" enabled="true">
                            <take-offline min-wait="60000" after-failures="3" />
                        </backup>
                    </backups>
```

I then run both of them and the UI seems to work fine and all until I try to click on "Manage backup site" -> "Push state", in which I get the error:

`no route to site2: dropping message.`

Why is it that it can't push the states? I am basing the configuration off the demo online (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.4/html/server_installation_and_configuration_guide/operating-mode#setup for reference)

Comment: are both servers running on the same LAN?

Comment: I think so? Does that make a difference?